# ListView item only first time

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Is there a way to detect when an `item` of `ListView` is created for the first time?

I want to write a code only when the `ListView` item is created for the first time, the code shouldn't be executed if the list has been recycled once.

Comment: could you post the code where you create the ListView?

Comment: I need the code in `Adapter`. I want to load an image 200ms after an item in `ListView` is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. I'll assume you meant: **"the first time a view item was created for position
N in my list"**.

What you should do is as follows:

```
class MyAdapter {

     private HashMap<Integer, Integer> processedPositions = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

     @Override
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (!processedPositions.containsKey(position)) {  // < ------------------
                   first time logic......
                   processedPositions.put(position, position); // and mark as processed
            else {
                   later times logic....
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you know how works ListView items.
Item are created by List each time when convertView is null in next method:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

But I think you need to show something only once for each item.

In this case you can create List of integers, and do something like this:

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ......
    if(listOfPositions.contains(position)){
      // we was here.
      firstTimeVisibleView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
      //do what you want.
      listOfPositions.add(position);
      firstTimeVisibleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    ......
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

create the listview and  use this pseudo code.

```
if (listView.getcount == 0)
    {
         //code to execute
    }
```

Comment: I need the code to be executed for each item only once. I want to load an image 200ms after an item in ListView is created.

Comment: then please phrase your question properly